looker studio parameter filter
I had created a parameter in looker studio as Region.
Ex:
Region: EAST
WEST,
NORTH,
SOUTH,
SOUTH-EAST,
....etc.
Users should be restricted to see the regions only they are assigned to. It should not display all regions for every users. I had created access table where users will be filtered through email address.  Can you please suggest how to modify and acheive this.
Thanks
